# a = b = 5 in VB.NET - impossible?

Tags: .net, vb.net, operators

Is it possible in VB.NET doing `a = b = 5`? (I know that `=` is a comparison operator too)

I mean do **not** result (if b = 2 by e.g.)

```
a = false
b = 2
```

HOW to do it, however, in situations like bellow?

---

The inconvenient caused this question in my code: some objects `a, b, .. z` are passed by ref in a method, if I don't initialize them compiler warns me that it shoudl be initialized(= Nothing by e.g.)

```
Dim a, b, c, d, z As GraphicsPath ' = Nothing is impossible, only each a part
DrawPaths(a, b, c, d, z)          ' DrawPaths sets a = new GraphicPath() etc.
```

Comment: The compiler is a bit stupid in this case, because you wouldn't need to initialize the a, b, c, d and z variables; they already have a value of Nothing.

Comment: @Meta-Knight: Yes... apparently there is no option in VB.NET like **out**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`a = b = 5` 
means

```
if b = 5 then a = true else a = false
```

if you want to assign the value 5 to a and to b at the same time, you must add it on a separate line :

```
b = 5
a = b
```

you can also write them on the same line but using the vb.net line separator :

```
b = 5 : a = b
```

Answer (score 6):

Because `=` in VB/VB.NET is also a comparison operator, so in that context it returns a boolean.

Comment: I think you'll just have to do it the long way and assign them all individually.

Comment: so, I suppose, the answer to "impossible?" is "Yes, impossible"?

Answer (score 2):

That's just the rules of the Basic language. Many languages uses different operators to distinguish between assingment and equality testing.

For example,

- **C/C++/C#/Java** uses `=` and `==`.
- **Pascal** uses `:=` and `=`.
- **Basic** does not.

Comment: so, I suppose, the answer to "impossible?" is "Yes, impossible"?